# Galleria: Thumbs only?

Tags: gallery, thumbnails, galleria

I'm using Galleria and trying to utilize just the thumbs and lightbox sections, so that i don't have a large image on the page. I'm looked at cmotion as an alternative but dont like the way it doesn't automatically adjust the thumb dimensions to fit the image. I was hoping i could add some code to only call the thumb part of the gallery? any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: nothing yet...quite new at this so don't know where to start.

Comment: @user1126789 have you gotten anywhere with this yet?

Answer (score 1):

The generated divs concerned are nested as follows:

```
<div class="galleria-container">
  <div class="galleria-stage">
    ...main image here...
  </div>  
  <div class="galleria-thumbnails-container">
    ...thumbnails here...
  </div>
</div>
```

**.galleria-stage** must have a proper height or the image gallery will fail but you can stop it from displaying with display:none.  However, both **.galleria-stage** and **.galleria-thumbnails-container** are absolutely positioned to sit one on top of the other, so you will still have an empty space where the main image should be.

css with !important provides a quick fix by overwriting the positions so they are both aligned to the top, one on top of the other.

```
.galleria-stage { display: none; }
.galleria-stage, .galleria-thumbnails-container {
 height: 200px !important; //thumb height
 top: 0px !important;
 bottom: 0px !important;
 left: 0px !important;
 right: 0px !important;
}
.galleria-thumbnails-container { z-index: 2 !important; }
```

Change height to your thumb height and change 0px if you want padding around your images.